# PHP images - Add image over another image that has been created with PHP

Tags: php, image, gd

Basically I have to work with a ID Card PHP thing that requires me to add the name of a participant and upload a picture. I have a basic template for the ID Card and I'm using PHP to add the name. I have to add the picture of the participant on a particular spot. The name is working but I cannot add a picture of the participant over the generated PHP image. Here's my code:

http://chopapp.com/#arcqwgf4

How should I go about adding the picture over the PHP generate image.

Sorry if this is confusing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already most of the way there using GD, what you need to do is use [imagecopymerge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) to draw one image on top of the other at a specified point on the base image. PHP.net has quite a few examples on the linked page.

Comment: What's the issue in this http://chopapp.com/#6m56tq6u it's not outputting an image.

Comment: What does the script output if you access it directly? Also, have you checked the error log to see if any errors are being thrown? I have a feeling it has to do with `$_POST['id']`

Comment: $_POST['id'] worked before I added the imagecopymerge function. It should output the final image on the screen but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: you appear to be passing 8 arguments and imagecopymerge requires 9, add an extra argument on the end of "100" to make it `imagecopymerge($jpg_image, $dst_image, 200, 100, 0, 0, 40, 40, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for things like these. There is a method named `combineImages()` with which you can achieve your goal.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it by the method that I used? I don't know Imagick :S

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) method in php.

I created an example here: http://artuc.my.phpcloud.com/artuc/ type name, id and select an image to place it.

Here is the code i used:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $canvasImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('sample.jpg');
    $bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($canvasImage, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($canvasImage, 0, 0, $bgcolor);

    //Place person picture
    $bgImage = $_POST['idPic'];
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($bgImage);
    $imageSize = getimagesize($bgImage);
    imagecopyresampled($canvasImage, $img, 15, 17, 0, 0, $imageSize[0], $imageSize[1], $imageSize[0], $imageSize[1]);

    $fontFile = "Arial.ttf";
    //Place person name
    $black = imagecolorallocate($canvasImage, 0, 0, 0);
    imagettftext($canvasImage, 18, 0, 220, 35, $black, $fontFile, $_POST['idName']);

    //Place person id
    $black = imagecolorallocate($canvasImage, 0, 0, 0);
    imagettftext($canvasImage, 18, 0, 220, 75, $black, $fontFile, $_POST['idNum']);

    //Save Image
    imagejpeg($canvasImage);
    imagedestroy($canvasImage);
```